# ProvidePlugin with preact config

Tags: webpack, preact

I'm looking to provide a plugin using `webpack.ProvidePlugin`. On a previous version of my project, I managed to provide it using this Webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        PIXI: 'pixi.js',
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

However, I can't seem to get the same result through the `preact.config.js` file:

```js
webpack(config, env, helpers, options) {
  /**
  * Function that mutates the original webpack config.
  * Supports asynchronous changes when a promise is returned (or it's an async function).
  *
  * @param {object} config - original webpack config.
  * @param {object} env - options passed to the CLI.
  * @param {WebpackConfigHelpers} helpers - object with useful helpers for working with the webpack config.
  * @param {object} options - this is mainly relevant for plugins (will always be empty in the config), default to an empty object
  **/
  // ...
  options = {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        PIXI: "pixi.js",
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

This returns `ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined` at runtime, which is the error I got in my early project when I wasn't providing the plugin through the `ProvidePlugin` method. How do I set  `preact.config.js` so it provides the plugin correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing into the `plugins` array instead similar to [this example in the docs](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/wiki/Config-Recipes#merge-static-assets-with-the-build-folder):

```js
export default {
  // ...
  webpack(config, env, helpers, options) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        PIXI: "pixi.js",
      }),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the solution:

```
export default {
  webpack(config, env, helpers, options) {
    const providePlugin = helpers.getPluginsByName(config, 'ProvidePlugin')[0];
    providePlugin.plugin.definitions['PIXI'] = 'pixi.js';
  }
}
```

https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/1208#issuecomment-636128394